Is there any way to connect my DIY graphic tablet to windows inking framework?
I have DIY a graphic tablet which send position, pressure and posture of pen data to PC by serial port. I want to connect the device to Windows inking platform. My question is how to connected my DIY graphic tablet to windows inking framework so that I can use windows inking framework on my device.
I have I tried the following methods：

I have read the windows.ui.input.inking UWP API document and run some demos. I know Windows.UI.Input.Inking give powerful APIs accessed to pen and inking. However those interfaces is only use develop app that use the pen/touch/mouse's input rather than develop a input device driver.

I try input Injection (Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection) which doesn't fully meet my needs. The reasons are as follows：

The X tilt or Y tilt properties in InjectedInputPenInfo is type of int, but tilt in PointerPoint.Properties which received on InkCanvas is type of float. It make precision lose.

PointerPoint.Properties has ZDistance properties while InjectedInputPenInfo doesn't have. It makes data lose.




Maybe windows inking support alse APIs to input pointer event. Or maybe I need to write some driver. I want to know to realize it.
Thanks.
Similar problem: How to generate stylus pen events and pressure in windows?

"int" is a function of "device independent (logical) pixels" in order to be able to scale to different sized devices.

Hi Gerry, thinks for help. "int" is type of tilt angle which unit is degree. It loss precision if the tilt is 12.3°. "Input injection doesn't fully meet needs" is that inking framework support float tilt angle while pen input injection only support int tilt angle. My device support high-precision tilt angle detecting, but when I send data by input injection the precision is losed.

Ink (input) "points" are also int's. I'm just explaining the reasoning behind (at least some) int's in the interface: scaling and device "break points". At "run time", I'm (almost) "sure", it will use interpolation to smooth things when they change. Why is a fraction of a degree in "tilt" important starting out? What happens at run time? "Offset" the number at run time if it's that important.
